# Django filter deep related models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

In my Django 3.2 app, my models have the following relations:

```
OperationDraft -> ForeignKey(Structure)
Structure -> ForeignKey(Customer)
Customer -> OneToOne(AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Now, when I create a new OperationDrat I have to limit the choice of the structure based on the user of its customer. If the user is not active then I cannot select the structure.

To achieve that I overrided formfield_for_foreignkey to OperationDraftAdmin class:

```
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        """Override formfield_for_foreignkey."""
        if db_field.name == "structure":
            # this doesn't work
            kwargs["queryset"] = Structure.objects.filter(customer__user__is_active=True)

            # this returns 0 results even if we have a customer with such user
            # kwargs["queryset"] = Structure.objects.filter(customer__user__username="user480")

        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

The filter should be:

`kwargs["queryset"] = Structure.objects.filter(customer__user__is_active=True)`

But it returns all the structures, even those ones with a customer bound to an inactive user.

URL: /operations/operationdraft/add/
My models (limited to relevant code):

```
@admin.register(OperationDraft)
class OperationDraftAdmin(OperationProxyAdmin):
    """Set OperationDraft Admin."""

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        """Override formfield_for_foreignkey."""
        if db_field.name == "structure":
            # this doesn't work
            kwargs["queryset"] = Structure.objects.filter(customer__user__is_active=True)

            # this returns 0 results even if we have a customer with such user
            # kwargs["queryset"] = Structure.objects.filter(customer__user__username="user480")

            # this works but it's not what I need
            # kwargs["queryset"] = Structure.objects.filter(customer__name="Customer249")

        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)


class Operation(models.Model, StatusLogMixin):
    structure = models.ForeignKey(
        Structure,
        verbose_name="struttura",
        related_name="operations",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )

class OperationDraft(Operation):
    """Define draft operation proxy model."""

    class Meta:
        """Define model Meta."""

        proxy = True
        verbose_name = "Intervento in bozza"
        verbose_name_plural = "01 - Inserimento Interventi"


class Customer(models.Model):
    """Customer model."""
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        verbose_name="utente web",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="customer",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        limit_choices_to={"groups__name": settings.CUSTOMER},
    )

class Structure(models.Model):
    """Model of the Structure."""

    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer,
        verbose_name="cliente",
        related_name="structures",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
```

I checked [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) and to me my query is correct but not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your models and the rest of the ModelAdmin?

Comment: `OperationDraft` is a proxy model. It's still not clear which ModelAdmin is assigned to which model and which admin URL you are viewing

Comment: @IainShelvington added decorator on OperationDraftAdmin and URL /operations/operationdraft/add/